# UWP Community Toolkit not building in Release mode?

Tags: xaml, uwp, expander, windows-community-toolkit

I am using UWP Community Toolkit with Template 10 in my UWP application.
Whenever i am trying to build my app in Release mode it is not building.But in Debug mode everything seems fine.

As per my research i found that UWP Community toolkit supports device family 10586 or higher in Windows 10.Does it mean that my machine which has 10240(lower version) build version will not be able to use UWP Community toolkit controls and my app must have 10586 as min version?

I am really confused and I want to use Expander control from UWP Community Toolkit but in release mode it is not able to build.Does anybody has any idea about this issue?

Ref - [Expander control from UWP Community](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/Expander/#expander-control)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should bump your version up to 10586. 10240 is way too old.

Comment: I have tried it but that is also not working.I created a new app with min version 10586 and installed both the libraries from npm but in release mode the app is not building.

Comment: Make sure you update all your nuget packages, especially the .net core for UWP.

Comment: After updating it gives an error that you should have VS 2017 for .NET core 5.3 version

Comment: You should really start using the latest version of VS...